# Как подключить кусок кода в шаблоне wp?

Tags: wordpress

Я создал шаблон страницы в wp. Но не пойму как вывести содержимое из `components/uslugi/uslugi.php`. Где то нужно подключать? К примеру   отображается, а как подключить мой компонент? Буду рад любой помощи!

в папке parts создал:
`uslugi.html` и прописал:

```
<!-- wp:theme/uslugi /-->
```

В `theme.json`

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/theme.json",
    "version": 2,
    "templateParts": [
        {
            "name": "header",
            "title": "Header",
            "area": "header"
        },
        
        {
            "name": "footer",
            "title": "Footer",
            "area": "footer"
        }
        ,
          {
            "name": "uslugi",
            "title": "Uslugi",
            "area": "uslugi"
        }
    ],
    "customTemplates": [
        {
            "name": "page-service",
            "title": "Service template"
        }
    ],
    "styles": {
        "spacing": {
            "blockGap": "0"
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        "spacing": {
            "blockGap": false,
            "units": [
                "%",
                "px",
                "em",
                "rem",
                "vh",
                "vw",
                "ch"
            ]
        },
        "appearanceTools": true,
        "color": {
            "defaultPalette": false,
            "defaultDuotone": false,
            "defaultGradients": false,
            "customGradient": false,
            "customDuotone": false,
            "gradients": [],
            "palette": [
                {
                    "name": "White",
                    "slug": "white",
                    "color": "#ffffff"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Black",
                    "slug": "black",
                    "color": "#000000"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

в `functions.php`

```
 <?php
    
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/setup.php';
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/scripts.php';
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/layout.php';
    require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/breadcrumbs.php';
    
    add_filter( 'default_wp_template_part_areas', 'themeslug_template_part_areas' );
    
    function themeslug_template_part_areas( array $areas ) {
        $areas[] = array(
            'area'        => 'uslugi',
            'area_tag'    => 'section',
            'label'       => __( 'Uslugi', 'themeslug' ),
            'description' => __( 'Uslugi', 'themslug' ),
            'icon'        => 'uslugi'
        );
    
        return $areas;
    }
```

В `components/uslugi/uslugi.php`

```
<?php

defined('ABSPATH') || exit;
?>
<? print_r("Здесь компонент услуг");?>
```

Answer (score 2):

> Я создал шаблон страницы в wp. Но не пойму как вывести содержимое из
> components/uslugi/uslugi.php.

1. Это НЕ шаблон. Если нужен шаблон страницы, то он должен быть в корне темы. Далее на выбор - либо прописанный заголовок и выбор шаблона при создании страницы, либо автоматическое подключение по имени файла в соответствии и иерархией. [Матчать](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%98%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2)
2. Содержимое должно хранится в базе, а не файлах.
   Если нужно подключить часть шаблона из внутренних файлов, то используется [get_template_part](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_template_part)